# SKScene superclass doesn't have a didMove method

Tags: swift, xcode, sprite-kit

Finally cracked open SpriteKit and Swift, but have fallen at first hurdle.

The Xcode linter/compiler is telling me that I'm trying to override a superclass method that doesn't exist. It's protesting that [SkScene](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/spritekit/skscene) does not have a [`didMove()`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/spritekit/skscene/1519607-didmove) method, even though the documentation seems to say otherwise.

Tried researching but I'm guessing it's a pretty popular error message that's easily resolved with a bit of research on the class hierarchies. I've not seen anything involving this specific context, though.

[image: Screenshot]

I'm using Xcode 7.3 and I initiated the boilerplate code by choosing 'Game' in the new project wizard.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Xcode 7.3 is pretty old.  It uses Swift 2.2, so the syntax is:

```
class GameScene: SKScene {
    override func didMoveToView(view: SKView) {
        //
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks. That was the issue. I thought I was up to date but my AppStore is lying to me about updates to Xcode.

Comment: What version of Mac OS are you running?  Latest Xcode needs latest Sierra 10.12.6 or High Sierra.

Comment: El Capitan... Tis currently downloading, perhaps I should stop it? Is there any way I can get a reasonably new version of Xcode running on El Capitan?

Comment: You can move up to Xcode 8.X.  You'll have to download from [Apple's Developer Site](https://developer.apple.com/download).

Comment: Great, I'll try 8.3 and see how I go. Thanks for your help.

Comment: Check out the Xcode page on [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Xcode).  It has lots of good info on versions.  Xcode 8.2.1 is the last version that runs on El Capitan, assuming you're at 10.11.5.

Comment: Good catch. Turns out 8.3 is the first to only support macOS Sierra. Another download cancelled, let's try 8.2 :-)